# TomEE Microprofile OpenAPI in Plume

Tags: openapi, apache-tomee, microprofile

I wrote a simple JAX-RS REST service (which is working as expected) and I'm trying to generate the OpenAPI documentation using microprofile. Therefore I added the following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-openapi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I deploy the application on TomEE 9.0.0 M7 Microprofil everything works as expected and the OpenAPI schema is reachable under http://localhost:8080/openapi. But when I deploy the same artifact to TomEE 9.0.0. M7 Plume/Webprofile/Plus the schema / endpoint is not available. What am I missing here? Is this a configuration issue? According to https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/tomee-webprofile-vs-tomee-microprofile-vs-tomee-vs-tomee-plume/ MicroProfile should be part of the other distributions of TomEE too...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! MP implementation is available on the others TOMEE Profiles, but you will need to add a flag.

`-Dtomee.mp.scan=all`

if you are running it trough maven plugin you should put the flag like this.

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${tomee.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <context>ROOT</context>
    <args>-Dtomee.mp.scan=all</args>
    <tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
    <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the Info! Does anybody know where to find this in the documentation?